# postgres $HOME directory unproperly set in Docker container created from official postgres Dockerfile

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've created a PostgreSQL 9.1 Docker container using [this official Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/35a09c34b04019c3942d13d78b99eab66bc4b3ad/9.1/Dockerfile).

To create my container, I've done this:

Step 1: create a volume for permanent postgres data

```
docker volume create --name postgres_data
```

Step 2: Start the postgres instance

```
docker run --name my_postgres_container -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=my_password -v postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres:9.1
```

My instance starts correctly, and I can connect with it, but:

**Problem 1: No logs**

```
docker logs my_postgres_container --> returns nothing
```

**Problem 2: Improperly configured $HOME directory**

```
docker exec -it my_postgres_instance /bin/bash --> enter as root
# su postgres --> change to postgres user

$ psql --> ok, can connect to my cluster
psql (9.1.20)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

$ pwd
/ --> Why do I directly go to / instead to /var/lib/postgresql/data ?

$ export 
export HOME='/home/postgres'
export PGDATA='/var/lib/postgresql/data'
```

**Why is HOME configured to that value? I was expecting $HOME equal to $PGDATA. Am I wrong?**

Comment: I just ran the command described on your question and I do see log statements. What Docker version are you on? Regarding the $HOME variable value the answer is here: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/35a09c34b04019c3942d13d78b99eab66bc4b3ad/9.1/Dockerfile#L5. The official images adds a **postgres** user but does not set the home directory to be **/var/lib/postgresql/data**

Comment: Ok, it's working now. I don't know why, but thanks.